# How to send large number of emails using php and shell command

Tags: php, codeigniter, shell-exec

Here I am facing a problem when I am send email in loop. The Details is given below:

I have a csv file called email.csv. I am uploading this file and read the email from this csv file.I am using codeignitor framework. The code for reading the csv file and send the emails, the code is given as follows.

```
 $file = $_FILES['email_from_file'][tmp_name];
                        $handle = fopen($file,"r");

                        if (($handle = fopen($file,"r")) !== FALSE) {
                            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                                $num = count($data);
                                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                                    $this->email->clear();
                                    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
                                    $this->email->to(trim($data[$c]));
                                    $this->email->from('admin@workerbee.com');
                                    $this->email->subject($data['news_letter_info'][0]['subject']);
                                    $this->email->message($data['news_letter_info'][0]['template_body']);
                                    $this->email->send();
                                }
                            }
                            fclose($handle);
                        }
```

when I am sending the email its take too much time to execute and sending the email. And my browser also became hang. So is there have any possible way to send these emails using shell command which will execute the php script in the background.

Thank in advance.

Comment: The `shell command` you want is the linux `cronjob`. Do not send all the emails in one loop. If you have a large number of emails, the server will probably not send them all.

Comment: @machineaddict: we select the file from admin section and from that csv file I have to read the emails and send the email notification to these emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this.

```
exec('php /<SERVER PATH>/send_bulkmail.php');
```

In your send_bulkmail.php use code to read file using fread() or file_get_content() and send mail in lood as you have done above.

Answer (score 0):

I use Cron job for this type of tasks.

Check crontab manual. http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man5/crontab.5.php

EX.

```
*/5 * * * * php /u1/dev/cuser5/scripts/cli.php --action project/.../messages/send-email.php
```

This mean. run the send-email file every 5 minutes every day.

NOTE: if you have to many emails to send then you should send the email in smaller groups.